# Running Typedoc on Project includes files from node_modules?

Tags: angular, typescript, typedoc, angular-package-format

I [have this project](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/is) setup with typedoc and the npm script (`npm run d`) used to work:

```
"d": "typedoc --out doc --exclude **/*.spec.ts ./projects/fs-is/src/lib"
```

I upgraded the project to Angular 12 (It uses the Angular Package Format) and now when typedoc is run it includes files from `node_modules` and fails:

```
Error: node_modules/@types/eslint/index.d.ts:474:43 - error TS2694: Namespace '"/Users/oleersoy/Github/is/node_modules/@types/estree/index"' has no exported member 'ImportExpression'.

474         ImportExpression?: ((node: ESTree.ImportExpression & NodeParentExtension) => void) | undefined;             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Also asked on Typedoc Github repository](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1718)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of the Typedoc Collaborators:

> You see that error because the eslint and estree (parser that eslint relies on) have mismatched versions. I'd recommend making the versions match if possible, or turning on `skipLibCheck`.

I ended up adding `skipLibCheck` to the `tsconfig.json` compiler options, and that fixed it.

## 2023-Jul

In order to get it to work now (July 2023) I also needed to add `typedoc.json` .... specifically the `"entryPointStrategy": "expand"` part ...

```
{
  "entryPointStrategy": "expand",
  "out": "docs"
}
```